# Text-to-speech: prosody transfer

Tags: text-to-speech

Probably "prosody transfer" isn't the right term, but I don't know what would be.

I'm looking for some solution, most likely a software library, that would allow me to:

- Record an utterance.
- Also provide a text transcription.
- Play it back using a different voice, but with intonation, stress, rhythm, etc. preserved from the original recording.

Alternatively, I'm also interested in ways of annotating the text with prosody information before feeding it into a text-to-speech system.

Could you please suggest me some software or libraries (preferably free and open-source, or at least cheap), or even just pointers about where to read up on such topics? Thanks.

(Note that I'm a software engineer, but new to TTS.)

Comment: Requesting resources such as libraries or the like are off-topic in SO: **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.**. More information in the next link: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @eyllanesc: Is there a Stack Exchange site where such a question would be appropriate?

Comment: From what I know, none of the sites allows such questions as it leads to spam.

Comment: You nicht Investigation https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @eyllanesc – maybe it's time to review list of [se] technology sites: https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology  (maybe there's a suitable site for couple  of years already...)

Comment: @miroxlav *From what I know* :P

Comment: @eyllanesc – just a heads-up to refresh the cache :) *From what I know*, there's no OS made by Google yet :)

Comment: @bummi: Oh, I didn't know about softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. Thanks!